# how to compute the spinach value by years?

Tags: r

I am forecasting agrofood based on several factors using R.But i have found the mse value for each item but i cannot find how to forecast the consumption of each item in each year.
structure(list(Year = 2016:2021, GDP = c(9544.25, 9969.5, 11086.11,
11231.54, 10361.28, 11407.68), Spinach = c(6.1, 7.7, 7.7, 8.4, 7.6, 8.2),

```
# Calculate the means and standard deviations for columns 2 and 4
mean_data <- c(mean(mydata[, 2]), mean(mydata[, 3]))
sd_data <- c(sd(mydata[, 2]), sd(mydata[, 3]))

# Scale only columns 2 and 4 using the specific means and standard deviations
data_scaled <- mydata
data_scaled[, c(2, 3)] <- scale(data_scaled[, c(2, 3)], center = mean_data, scale = sd_data)


# Create an index for splitting the data
index <- sample(1:nrow(data_scaled), round(0.50 * nrow(data_scaled)))

# Create the training and testing datasets
train_data <- as.data.frame(data_scaled[index, ])
test_data <- as.data.frame(data_scaled[-index, ])

# Get the column names of the scaled data
n = names(data_scaled)
n

# Build a neural network model to predict 'Rice' based on 'Inflation.Rate.' using the training data
net = neuralnet(Spinach ~ GDP, data=train_data, hidden=c(5,5), 
                linear.output=TRUE)
plot(net)


# Compute predictions on the testing data
# Calculate Mean Squared Error (MSE) for the predictions
predict_net_test <- compute(net, test_data[,c("GDP", "Spinach")])
# Calculate Mean Squared Error (MSE) for "Spinach" predictions
actual_spinach_values <- test_data$Spinach
predict_net_test <- predict_net_test$net.result
MSE.net <- mean((actual_spinach_values - predict_net_test)^2)

cat("Mean Squared Error (MSE) for 'Spinach' predictions:",MSE.net, "\n")
```

Comment: Hi Harika! Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you could share a bit of your data with `mydata |> head() |> dput()` that would be great! Also, where is it going wrong with your code right now? It seems like you are making predictions with the `compute(net, test_data[,c("GDP", "Spinach")])` line, but I might be wrong

Comment: hi i cant upload my full code here

Comment: I'm not asking you to upload your full ***dataset***, just the first few rows, hence `head()`

Comment: structure(list(Year = 2016:2021, GDP = c(9544.25, 9969.5, 11086.11, 
11231.54, 10361.28, 11407.68), Spinach = c(6.1, 7.7, 7.7, 8.4, 7.6, 8.2), 
   GDP is my independent variable and spinach is my dependent variable

Comment: Harika, edit your question to add it to it please :-)

Comment: Done sir.I have already edited the question

Comment: That looks like the start of the dput output but not all of it...

Comment: @Harika please retry doing it. Post the entirety of what you get from that thing into your question, not just the start.